# Seek to a random point and play for some seconds in a video

Tags: command-line, video, vlc

Like this:

I have a 60-second video

I want to have a loop for this:

1. For variable A is a random integer in range from 0 to 58.
2. Go to A-th seconds in the video.
3. Play 2 seconds and go back step 1.

I use VLC media player.

Answer (score 1):

Haha, the first person who answers this question is the person who asked it.

I use VLC, my video is a MP4 file. This works for me:

```
$ DIS=$( ffmpeg -i "the_path_of_your_video" 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,// | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }' | cut -f1 -d. ) # get video Duration In Seconds
$ COS=  # a integer: the Count Of Seconds to play every time
$ RTP=$( expr $DIS - $COS ) # Range To Play is from 0 to $RTP
$ while true; do cvlc --start-time $(( ( RANDOM % $RTP )  + 0 )) "the_path_of_your_video" --run-time $COS vlc://quit; done
```

In case in the question:

```
$ DIS=60
$ COS=2
$ RTP=58 # 60 - 2
$ while true; do cvlc --start-time $(( ( RANDOM % 58 )  + 0 )) "the_path_of_my_video" --run-time 2 vlc://quit; done
$ # A in the question is $(( ( RANDOM % 58 )  + 0 ))
$ # Close  terminal window to kill this proccess
```